# C function to escape string for shell command argument?

Tags: c, shell, function, escaping

What function should I use to escape strings for shell command argument in C?

1. I have a string:

   `This is a string with () characters`
2. This will be error:

   `echo This is a string with () characters`
3. These are OK:

   `echo "This is a string with () characters"`

   `echo This is a string with \(\) characters`

Is there a predefined function convert #2 to #3 in C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replacing all instances of `'` with `'\''` then enclosing the whole string in single quotes (`'`) is one safe way. This works even with embedded newlines. Another method would be to insert `\` before each character, except that then you have to do some special treatment for newlines since `\` followed by a newline is ignored by the shell, not treated as a literal newline. You'd have to surround newlines with `'` (single quotes).

Comment: try this with string: a'b.   for me, echo 'a\'b' .... doesn't work in bash, but echo 'a'"'"'b' does....

Comment: @ErikAronesty: I said to replace `'` with `'\''`, not with `\'`.

Comment: Note that quoting `'` results in `''\'''`, which is actually a sequence of three strings which get appended in evaluation. Therefore this is no real quotation.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r: Citation needed. Your comment does not match how shell field splitting and quote removal work even conceptually. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no predefined function.

However, I believe it's sufficient to just enclose any shell argument in single quotes, and making sure that single quotes are escaped.

That's the logic of the [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function in PHP and I believe it works reasonably well.

Comment: In context of shells note that there is a differece between qouting with single or double quotes. With double quotes [you have to escape $ and `as well](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes).

Comment: Futher note that shells do not allow single quotes in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

C is not my language of choice, but here's what I came up with (having to answer the same question, myself).

```
#include <stdio.h>     // sprintf
#include <stdlib.h>    // malloc
#include <string.h>    // strlen

char* escapeshellarg(char* str) {
    char *escStr;
    int i,
        count = strlen(str),
            ptr_size = count+3;

    escStr = (char *) calloc(ptr_size, sizeof(char));
    if (escStr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    sprintf(escStr, "'");

    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\'') {
                    ptr_size += 3;
            escStr = (char *) realloc(escStr,ptr_size * sizeof(char));
            if (escStr == NULL) {
                return NULL;
            }
            sprintf(escStr, "%s'\\''", escStr);
        } else {
            sprintf(escStr, "%s%c", escStr, str[i]);
        }
    }

    sprintf(escStr, "%s%c", escStr, '\'');
    return escStr;
}
```

Given `escape'this'`, it will output `'escape'\''this'\'''`, which can then be passed to `echo`.

```
$ echo 'escape'\''this'\'''
escape'this'
```

Comment: isn't realloc escpensive operation? I remember that it's possible that the whole string is copied to a new place. It would be better to allocate 2*str_size at the beginning. You don't often use arguments with a lot of `'` but still...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing pre-defined, and which characters need escaping depends on your shell. Look at the docs for your shell, and replace each X with \X. Using double quotes " will require the same treatment if the string you're enclosing contains a ".

Also note that this will get more complicated if you intend to encapsulate more complicated expressions (anything compounded with a ';', for example)

Answer (score 1):

Replace every single quote `'` with `'\''` then enclose the resulting string between single quotes `'`:

```
char *escapeShellArg( char *arg )
{
    char        *esc;
    uint16_t    i,
                j,
                n;

    n = strlen( arg );

    esc = calloc( 1, n * 4 + 3 );

    esc[0] = '\'';
    j = 1;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if( arg[ i ] == '\'' )
        {
            esc[ j   ] = '\'';
            esc[ j+1 ] = '\\';
            esc[ j+2 ] = '\'';
            esc[ j+3 ] = '\'';
            j += 4;
        }
        else
        {
            esc[ j++ ] = arg[ i ];
        }
    }

    esc[ j ] = '\'';

    return esc;
}
```